# Firestore not showing updated document after array update

Tags: node.js, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function in Firebase, and it updates an array inside a document using this method:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

However, when I try to then get the updated version of the document, it displays what it was before then array update. Here is my code:

eventUpdated is not showing the correct version before the array update.

```
if(isPut(request)){

    //All new additions
    const userId = request.body.userId;
    const eventId = request.body.eventId;
    const attStatus = request.body.attStatus;

    try {

        let eventsRef = db.collection('events').doc(eventId);

        if (attStatus === true) {
            // Add a new ID to the "eventAttendanceList" array field.
            let arrUnion = eventsRef.update({
                eventAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)
            });
            // Remove a ID from the "eventNonAttendanceList" array field.
            let arrRm = eventsRef.update({
                eventNonAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
            });


        }
        else if (attStatus === false) {
            // Add a new ID to the "eventNonAttendanceList" array field.
            let arrUnion = eventsRef.update({
                eventNonAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)
            });
            // Remove a ID from the "eventAttendanceList" array field.
            let arrRm = eventsRef.update({
                eventAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
            });

        }
        else {
            //If you do anything other than true or false, it will just remove the userId from both attending and non-attending
            let arrUnion = eventsRef.update({
                eventAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
            });
            let arrRm = eventsRef.update({
                eventNonAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
            });

        }

            let eventUpdated = await db.collection('events').doc(eventId).get()
            return response.status(200).json({status: "200", message: "Event RSVP successfully updated", event: eventUpdated.data()}).send;


    } catch(err) {
        return response.status(500).json({status: "500", message: "Event RSVP could not be updated"}).send;
    }

} else {
    return response.json({status: "ERR", message: "Please send a PUT request."}).send;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire code of your Cloud Function. Seeing the trigger is important for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Sure, I have updated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a set of asynchronous [`update()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update) methods but you don't wait that they complete before calling the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#get) method and sending the response.

So you should also use `await` for the `update()` methods, as follows:

```
let eventsRef = db.collection('events').doc(eventId);

if (attStatus === true) {
    // Add a new ID to the "eventAttendanceList" array field.
    await eventsRef.update({
        eventAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)
    });
    // Remove a ID from the "eventNonAttendanceList" array field.
    await eventsRef.update({
        eventNonAttendanceList: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
    });
}
else if (attStatus === false) {
    //...
}
else {
    //...
}

let eventUpdated = await db.collection('events').doc(eventId).get()
response.status(200).json({ status: "200", message: "Event RSVP successfully updated", event: eventUpdated.data() }).send;
```

---

I make the assumption that you are using an [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=1). Note that you don't need to do `return` but just call `response.redirect()`, `response.send()`, or `response.end()`. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and the corresponding [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0&feature=youtu.be).

---

Also note that if you call several document writes or updates in a row, you might use a [batched write](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/WriteBatch.html).

Comment: Thanks so much, that has helped. Really appreciate it.